# Error, while trying to access the webservices from InfoPath form

Tags: 2010, infopath, web-services, error

I am getting the following error while trying to access a custom webservice from an InfoPath form to fetch some data. I have already gone through the actions described in the error message, but the problem still persists.

> A query to retrieve form data cannot be completed because this action would violate cross-domain restrictions.
>
> If this form template is published to a SharePoint document library, cross-domain access for user form templates must be enabled under InfoPath Forms Services in SharePoint Central Administration, and the data connection settings must be stored in a UDC file in a data connection library in the same site collection.
>
> If this is an administrator-approved form template, the security level of the form must be set to full trust, or the data connection settings must be stored in a UDC file by using the Manage data connection files option under InfoPath Forms Services in SharePoint Central Administration.
>
> A query to retrieve form data cannot be completed because this action would violate cross-domain restrictions.

Comment: How are you publishing the form? Where is the webservice located?

Answer (score 0):

So you have ensured that the "allow cross domain connection" setting in Central Admin is ticked.

If you are behind a proxy server, you will need to add this to your web.config of your SP web application:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy proxyaddress="http://myproxy" bypassonlocal="true" />
      <bypasslist>
        <add address="mycustomwebservice.com" />
         </bypasslist>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```